# Date Picker / calendar UI Component with draggable date ranges

Tags: java, datepicker, client-side, uicontrol, calendar-control

I'm looking for a datepicker control (HTML + JavaScript / Flex) that allows selecting a range of dates by dragging along the calendar dates (just like in Google Calendar or Outlook)

It can be open source (preferable obviously) or commercial, and should be server technology agnostic.

---

Outlook date range selection

[Outlook date range selection http://www.bowdoin.edu/it/how-to/email/outlook/images/small_calendar.jpg](http://www.bowdoin.edu/it/how-to/email/outlook/images/small_calendar.jpg)

---

Google calendar date range selection

[image: Google calendar date range selection]
<sub>(source: [ischool.tv](http://ischool.tv/googleapps/files/2008/02/calendar-custom-date-range.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

I know it isn't dragable so I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for.